# How to convert a list into a complex table with rearranged and individually named columns?

Tags: r

I have a list (called list) with 30 data frames that all have individual names (named after firms) and consist of the output of a regression. The data frames all look like this:

```
term         estimate std.error statistic p.value
(Intercept)  0.0012   0.000     2.84      0.00
x$Return     0.8119   0.055     14.49     1.08
x$ReturnDum  0.2989   0.083     0.10      0.05
```

For my output, I need a (pdf or png) file with a regression table, that consists of all the outputs above. The table should look something like this:

```
Firm    (Intercept)  x$Return    x$ReturnDum
Firm1    0.0012       0.8119      0.2989
        (0.000)***   (0.055)     (0.083)**
Firm2    0.0242       0.2359      0.0239
        (0.000)***   (0.050)**   (0.909)
...
```

Basically, it should contain four columns (called Firm, (Intercept), x$Return and x$ReturnDum) and 30 rows, one row for each firm. Each row should contain the firm name (under Firm), the value of the estimate and the value of the std.error for each remaining column (preferably together with the significance stars - 3 stars for a p.value < 0.01, 2 stars for a p.value < 0.05 and 1 star for a p.value < 0.1, no star for everything above).

I have not figured out how to transform my list into this kind of table and would appreciate any help as I am still a beginner with R! Thanks.

Comment: To save you trouble later, don't ever call a list 'list'!

Comment: The `***` and the `p.value` are not in sync

Comment: @akrun sorry fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `map` from `purrr` to loop over the `list`, `mutate` the data.frame column 'std.error' to `format` into a string by concatenating `"***"` when the `p.value` is less than 0.25 or else return the column as a `character` type (`case_when` checks type), `select` the columns of interest, transpose (`t`), convert to data.frame, and create an id column 'Firm' based on the names of the `list` (by default, if there is no names, adds sequence number).  Note that `map` returns a `list`, while the suffix `_df` converts it to a single data.frame output by row binding the `list` elements

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(lst1, ~ 
          .x  %>%
          mutate(std.error = case_when(p.value < 0.05 ~
                   str_c("(", std.error, ")", "***"), 
                     TRUE ~ as.character(std.error)), 
                 estimate = round(estimate, 3)) %>%        
          select(estimate, std.error) %>%
          t %>%
           as.data.frame , .id = 'Firm')
```

---

For multiple categories, an easier option is `cut` or `findInterval`

```
map_df(lst1, ~ 
     .x %>%
       mutate(std.error = str_c("(", round(std.error, 3), ")", 
            c("****", "***", "**", "*")[findInterval(p.value, 
            c(0.01, 0.05, 0.1))+1]),
            estimate = round(estimate, 3)) %>%
       select(estimate, std.error) %>%
       t %>%
       as.data.frame %>% 
       rename_all(~ c("Intercept)",  "x$Return",    "x$ReturnDum")), .id = "Firm")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this just rearranges my data but it is still in a list and not in the format I need...

Comment: @User2010S  Use `map_df` instead of `map`

Comment: Please, show the result of your code for easier comparison with OP's expectations. Thank you.

Comment: @akrun This already looks better since it gives me one table as output, however, now I have 5 rows for each firm, including the values for statistic and p.value - how can I delete this?
And is there a way to add the significance stars?

Comment: @User2010S  You can use `select` before the `t` step.  Updated the post

Comment: I found that when using the pixiedust package, I can arrange the output a bit better, however, it still gives me a list as output and the columns and rows are switched:
`require(pixiedust)
dust(df) %>% 
      sprinkle(cols = c("estimate", "std.error", "statistic"), round = 3) %>%
      sprinkle(cols = "p.value", fn = quote(pvalString(value))) %>% 
      sprinkle_colnames("Term", "Coefficient", "SE", "T-statistic", 
                        "P-value")`

Comment: @User2010S  Thank you for the comments.  Your p.value in the post is not sync to test the codes

Comment: @akrun, thanks, I fixed the p.values! So far the table looks close to what I need, two more questions: is there a way to round all values to 3 points after the comma? And How can I add the two- and one-star p.values in the code (right now I added them with pipes but for a 3-star value the 2- and 1-stars also appear)?

Comment: @User2010S As you showed a package, there is another package as well to do this automatically.  But, in the current code, you can add couple of statements in the `case_when` i.e. `case_when(p.value < 0.05 ~
                   str_c("(", std.error, ")", "***"), p.value < 0.1 ~ str_c("(", std.error, ")", "**"), ...`

Comment: @User2010S  BTW, where is the comma you mentioned.  Is it the `.`  If that iss the case, you can use `round` `str_c("(", round(std.error, 3), ")", "***"`

Comment: @akrun amazing, thank you! Yes, sorry I meant the point not comma. How can I round the estimate to 3 values as well? And is it possible to name the columns (now named V1, V2 and V3)?

Comment: @akrun nearly perfect, only problem is that now I have 4 stars for p.values < 0.01 and so on - how do I write it so that I have 3 stars for p.values < 0.01, 2 stars for p.value < 0.05, 1 star for p.value < 0.1 and no stars (just the value) for everything above?

Comment: @User2010S  Can you change it in the `findInterval` breaks.  I am doing this without the reproducible example.  So you can change that `****` to `***`

Comment: @akrun Awesome, I changed it in the Interval breaks. Thank you very much for your help!!!